# Need to set the minimum width for Click & drag column headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set the maximum width for the table header while click and drag.

I had tried the max-width and width in the css.

```
th {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 5px;
}
```

But no use on that. Here is the link for my code:

https://codepen.io/jasongardner/pen/QNOXym

I need to fix the width for drag the table for certain distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your problem. Change your Javascript to this:

```
$(function() {
    var startX,
         startWidth,
         $handle,
         $table,
         pressed = false;

    $(document).on({
        mousemove: function(event) {
            if (pressed) {
                var newWidth = startWidth + (event.pageX - startX);
                if (newWidth > 300) {
                    $handle.width(300);
                } else {
                $handle.width(startWidth + (event.pageX - startX));
                }
            }
        },
        mouseup: function() {
            if (pressed) {
                $table.removeClass('resizing');
                pressed = false;
            }
        }
    }).on('mousedown', '.table-resizable th', function(event) {
        $handle = $(this);
        pressed = true;
        startX = event.pageX;
        startWidth = $handle.width();

        $table = $handle.closest('.table-resizable').addClass('resizing');
    }).on('dblclick', '.table-resizable thead', function() {
        // Reset column sizes on double click
        $(this).find('th[style]').css('width', '');
    });
});
```

This is the code I changed:

```
if (pressed) {
   var newWidth = startWidth + (event.pageX - startX);
       if (newWidth > 300) {
           $handle.width(300);
       } else {
           $handle.width(startWidth + (event.pageX - startX));
       }
 }
```

I created the variable "newWidth" and check if it's bigger than 300. Only when it's smaller, it sets the new width. So actually you can just replace the 300 with any number you want to define as the max-width.

Hope this helps